# How do Dvati work with Incarnum?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, meldshaping

Okay, I love [Dvati](http://dnd.arkalseif.info/races/dragon-compendium--109/dvati--31/index.html), because a race that is two bodies with one soul is awesome. But I sure wish they'd clarified how they worked a little more with the non-Vancian magic systems of D&D. This marks the third in a series of questions on the race, preceded by [how they work with bardic music](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140947/can-dvati-bards-war-chanters-sing-multiple-songs-at-once) and [how they work with Tome of Battle maneuvers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140952/how-do-dvati-work-with-maneuvers/140953#140953). Gentlebeings, how do Dvati work with Incarnum feats, meldshaping, and chakra-binding?

Obviously, each body has the same feats and knows the same soulmelds. But do they have to split the number of soulmelds they can shape between each body (as well as chakra-binds), or does each body get the full package? For either case, do they have to mirror each other or can each body have a different 'load-out'? Or can only one body have shaped and/or bound soulmelds, like casting spells? I think it's fair to assume they share a single essentia pool, but who spends the swift action to shift essentia around? Incarnum magic items?

My thought is that you treat them as a single character; they each have the same soulmelds shaped/bound and the same distribution of essentia at all times, but what are your thoughts? As with the previous questions, I welcome answers of any justification, from flavor to RAW to balance to fun factor.

Answer (score 1):

**The Way I see it with the rules we have:**
Dvati twins are intended to be one single character but for some rules they are treated as 2 different entities:

- They both benefit from feats, however if the feat gives only a single
  soulmeld such as *Shape Soulmeld,* you still get one. (feats such as *toughness* benefit both twins IMO since they both get the CON bonus to life and 3 HP/2 would not be fun)
- The same logic can be applied with class abilities that gives a bonus to a pool of something such as spells, bardic music, soulmelds or a fixed number to something else (official rule)
- *Extra Chakra Bind* states:

> Benefit:The number of chakras to which you can bind soulmelds
>   increases by one.

So if your ''character'' could have 3 chakra binds and now 4, it's 4 across the twins

- There is always some exceptions such as personal spells for the Dvati
  twins:

> Personal  spells (those with a target of "you") affect  both  twins 
>   as  long  as  they  are  on  the  same  plane.  Otherwise,  they 
>   affect  only the  caster.

- My suggestion to optimize this would be to use the *Shape Soulmeld*
  feat to get extra soulmelds beyond the limit of your chosen meldshaper class if you have one (this
  way you don't need to have so much Constitution and you can bypass the ''maximum soulmeld'' given by the  meldshaper class with this but the maximum essentia invested in each soulmeld is still capped by level) in conjonction with
  *Share Soulmeld* wich can be used with an ally wich you have a special bond (it says familiar, mount or animal companion **with whom you can share spells**, but I
  think it is reasonable to allow this with ''yourself''because Dvati can share **some** spells (**see *Spell Conductor* below**) a way around
  this if the DM is severe and does not accept is to simply shape the
  soulmeld:*soulspark familiar* wich would benefit both twins if they
  stay within 5 feet of each other,since twin A shares to the familiar and the familiar shares his soulmeld benefit to you too, but I don't know if a DM would accept that the benefit giving from twin A to the familiar would transfer back to twin B as well but I would just simply allow share soulmeld to work with twins. Might be OP too, for balance reasons, testing should be done, but taking *shape soulmeld* a few times to fill the empty slots is 100% within the rules though)
- For essentia ''movement'' I guess the twin moving the essentia must
  be the one spending the action, he could want to take some from the
  other twin, give some to his twin, it's the same soul so no conflict
  really, but I guess I would limit this to 5 feet from each other for
  the transfer of essentia but since spells can be shared across the same plane... why not allow this too?
- Quote from *Dragon Compendium* p.17:

> A pair  of  dvati  twins  shares  all  class  abilities  and  spells 
>   slots between  them.  For  example, a  3rd-level dvati bard can use
>   bardic music three times per day in  total, not three times  for  each
>   twin.  Personal  spells (those with a target of "you") affect  both 
>   twins  as  long  as  they  are  on  the  same  plane.  Otherwise, 
>   they  affect  only the  caster.  Other  spells  function  as  normal.
>   For example, a touch  spell normally  affects  only the  specific 
>   twin touched. **The  spell  conductor  ability  (detailed  below) 
>   allows  the  dvati  to   share   some  spells**.  A  mind-affecting
>   ability  or  spell  that   affects   one twin  affects both  of them.
>   If a single  such  ability  targets both  twins  at the  same time,
>   they make  only  one  save between them. Dvati twins share one mind.

This officialy answers a part of your question and other questions for bardic music for a pool of abilities etc.

From *Dragon Compendium* p.18

> Spell Conductor: A dvati twin  can choose  to  shift  a  spell that 
>   affects  him  to his twin  so long  as both  of  them are on the same
>   plane. The shifted  spell must have a range of touch and  it must 
>   also be harmless. Using  this  ability  requires  a move  action  to 
>   focus  and   channel   the   spell's   power.  Aside   from   the
>   change  in  target,  the  spell's  duration  and   effects   continue 
>   as normal.

Comment: Just to be clear, only the twin ''wearing'' the soulmeld (it's a magic item after all) has the benefit, unless shape soulmeld is accepted by the DM.